How to *broadcast* ping a host under an IPv6 prefix?
Background: I want to make use of the IPv6 address my ISP provided, to access my home computer. I've got a NAS that can be accessed using an app over public network, and I can see its IPv6 address in the app.
This got me thinking - if I know the network prefix of my home network, can I broadcast ping to discover the IPv6 address of my computer?

There's no broadcast in IPv6, only unicast and multicast. Sorry, home networking, consumer-grade hardware and host configurations/issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic].
